# Unable to refer to contents of dll file

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have a C# website running in IIS. I need to consume a web service in my aspx page. I created a proxy class using the command wsdl.exe and generated a dll for it. I copied the dll under bin directory but I am unable to refer to the proxy class from my *.aspx.cs* file.

I get an error:

> CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestSearchProxy' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I tried adding the assembly reference in web.config using the following syntax:

```
<add assembly="TestSearchProxy, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
```

I am unable to get the PublicKeyToken for the dll since the dll is not strongly typed.

I still get the above mentioned error even after adding the assembly. I need to make the changes directly to the website in IIS and cant make the changes in Visual studio.

Please help me out with this issue.

Comment: Are you using a web project or web site?

Comment: Just copy the file with the class to the same location as your project files (e.g. your .cs files) and give it the same namespace. Class is **not** an assembly.

Comment: why have you created a dll for webservice? To consume a webservice, go to references and add a reference to your webservice.

Comment: like I mentioned, I am not making the changes in Visual studio. I need to manually make the changes to the files and copy them to IIS directly. So I will not be able to add a service reference.

Comment: I copied the proxy class to the same location as my .aspx and .aspx.cs files and made sure that the proxy class has the default namespace. I still get the same error when I add the code "TestSearchProxy searchProxy = new TestSearchProxy();" in my .aspx.cs file.

Comment: Here are the details of the proxy: Proxy class name - TestSearchProxy.cs , Namespace - WService, DLL Name - TestSearchProxy.dll     In my .aspx.cs file I have included the statement using WService; and in the method I am referring to the class as TestSearchProxy searchProxy = new TestSearchProxy();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am finally able to solve this issue. Here is a very useful link I found after lot of searching.
http://www.sitepoint.com/net-web-services-5-steps-3/

Here is the key points I learnt with this excercise

If the dll is directly added under /bin directory then the assembly reference need not be added to web.config

One silly mistake I was doing was I was declaring the class using the same name as the proxy class file name. The class name was TestSearch and the proxy file name was TestSearchProxy. I blame my Java background for this anyways. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of examples around of how to do this, including on the MSDN site.  Check some of these out.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1d42da/web-service-basics/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wbhsy70(v=vs.80).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186209(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: All the examples mention changes that should be done in Visual studio. I am looking for a solution which involves manually making the changes.

Comment: I found this thread, it's old but might point you in the right direction.  http://forums.asp.net/t/1520647.aspx/1  Sorry I couldn't solve it for you.  I've never done this outside of Visual Studio.